# How to get the modal to disappear after few seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I am using Iframe inside modal and I am hiding div containing modal after few seconds but actual screen does not get to focus, its still faded out. please check below images for more clarity. one more question, is there any way to change the player bar i am getting below the video to play and pause. Its real boring.
[image]

This main page which is supposed to in focus, like other normal pages but its still faded.[image]

**strong text**

code is here,

```
<div class="logo" id="div3">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <iframe id="Video" width="900" height="500" src="C:\Users\deeptim\Downloads\picture_shop_logo.mp4" allowfullscreen ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And functions are

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
           setTimeout(function () {
                $("div#logo_text").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $("div#logo_text").hide();
                $("div#logo_img").show();
                $("div#div3").hide();
                $("div#myCarousel").show();
              });
          }, 5000);
       });

  setTimeout(function () {
        $('#div3').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = $("#Video").attr('src');

        $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#Video").attr('src', '');
        });

        $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#Video").attr('src', url);
        });

        $("#myModal").modal(); //Display modal on load

    });
```

Is there any way to achieve above requirement ?

Comment: What code you have done to hide the modal ?

Comment: please add what you done till now, so that it would be easy to suggest a solution

Comment: Added please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("#myModal").modal("hide")` to actually `hide` the modal rather than hiding individual components separately. Also I don't understand why you have two `timeouts` with exact same delay. Just try the following.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           setTimeout(function () {
                $("div#logo_text").fadeOut("slow", function () {

                $("div#logo_img").show();

                //Hide modal window
                //////////////////////////////////////
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                //////////////////////////////////////

                $("div#myCarousel").show();
              });
          }, 5000);
       });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = $("#Video").attr('src');

        $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#Video").attr('src', '');
        });

        $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#Video").attr('src', url);
        });

        $("#myModal").modal("show"); //Display modal on load

    });
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. I was changing other two image after video gets over but now I removed its not good programming style because if user closes the video before it finished they wont find the images until 5 seconds.  One more question is there any possibility to change the player. the payer bar i am getting below is real boring ?

Comment: @deeptimullur Glad to hear that.

Comment: could you please try to answer this, One more question is there any possibility to change the player. the payer bar i am getting below is real boring ?

Comment: @deeptimullur That should go into an another question ;). I think you use the default HTML5 player. If so there are libraries that can change the skin of your player easily. Take a look at this library. http://videojs.com/